# Specifying width for :vsplit in vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to specify a width when doing :vsplit?
Also, is there a way to increase or decrease the width on a vertically splitted window? Ctrl-w + and Ctrl-w - seems to be working on only horizontally split windows.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to `:help :vsplit`, it takes an optional numeric argument as a prefix, e.g., `:80vs`. Try it out!

*Edit*: I guess I forgot to mention. You can control the width with `Ctrl-W <` and `Ctrl-W >`

For more info, read the manual at `:help windows`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can prefix a number to the command, n00b ;)

Comment: No problem, heh. Vim is one of those editors where pretty much everyone is a newb. You just keep learning new stuff about it all the time :)

Comment: Wow, I had no clue about this command...usually I just used the built in tabs in gVim and that could be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Any way to grow/shrink it more than one step? Hitting `Ctrl-W <` several times is pretty annoying.

Comment: @JordanScales It accept a `{count}` before you give the command. `23 <C-W> <` repeats the command 23 times.

Comment: You can use `Ctrl-w =` to make the splits equal size rather than trial and error resizing

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-W n < works, replace n with the number of steps you want to move.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use for example 80| to set your current split width to 80 columns

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the adjusted windows width, be sure the cursor is placed inside it and set the boolean

`:set winfixwidth`

This prevents from unwanted automatic resize of the such locked window width if some other window command like `CTRL-=` ("make all windows equal") is applied.

`:set nowinfixwidth` with the cursor placed inside the appropriate window disables the lock.

`:mksession` stores the window arrangement as calling vim again from the command line like
`vim -S Session.vim &` restores it.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
:vs
:vertical resize 30
```

and:

```
:sp
:resize 30
```

I have an Alt+E binding for a vertical file-explorer pane 60 chars wide:

```
:vs +Explore<CR>:vertical resize 60<CR>
```

Admittedly, I didn't know about the simple `:60vs` or `:60sp` thing in Luis' answer when I wrote that macro.